# Preserve objects between wcf calls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

This should be fairly basic, but say I have a Public property as local variable on my WCF service, and I set this in one call to the service. Is there a way to preserve that data for another call to the service? (Without writing the data to xml or a db, and re-referencing it or anything like that)

Executing the calls from the Winform:

```
Public Class ClientSideWinForm

    Private proxy As ServiceReference.Client

    Private Sub Client_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        proxy = New ServiceReference.Client
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStartTests_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStartTests.Click
        addToTxtResults("Try Chk Program Valid...")
        Try
            addToTxtResults(proxy.RequestChkValidProgram("Some-serial-number")) 'returns true or false and instanciates the object server side

            addToTxtResults(proxy.RequestFirstName()) ' returns nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            addToTxtResults(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The service itself (dumbed down a bit, but the behaivor still exists):

```
Public Class Service
    Implements IService

Public Property X As String

Function RequestChkValidProgram(ByVal strSerialNumber As String) As Integer Implements IService.RequestChkValidProgram
        X = "hello"
End Function

Function RequestFirstName() As String Implements IService.RequestFirstName
    Return X
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Looks like if I change the InstanceContextMode to Single the information persists between calls. Thank you everyone. 

If anyone would like to elaborate on why this may be a bad idea, I would truly like to know. Again, thanks! StackOverflow is quite amazing.

Comment: state in web services, in general, should be avoided. You also now need to interlock access to your state so that two calls don't overwrite each other.

Comment: @John Saunders: any chance you have a link that further describes how to interlock access? Is it done by wrapping the code with by lock(this){ doStuff(); }, using System.Threading.Interlock.Increment(counter); for counters, and comparing values before overwriting them?

Comment: any of the above. I just mean you need to prevent simultaneous modification of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, your service implementation's state is lost between service calls. You should look into setting the [InstanceContextMode ServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752230.aspx) of your service implementation - it sounds like it's currently set to `PerCall`, such that every service call gets its own instance. `PerSession` or `Single` may be better alternatives.

And while I don't necessarily agree with @John Saunders that this is a bad idea, it would be useful to have more details about what you're trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: I've added a little code to try to clarify what I'm trying to do here. It does seem like you have the correct interpretation though. Thanks!

Comment: @Kosko Thanks for the elaboration, but we'll probably need a look at the service-side implementation (i.e. whatever contains the property that isn't persisting between calls) to get an idea what could be going wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single instance of your service, then you can preserve data from one call to the next. You should consider telling us why you want to do this, as it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It is a single instance of the service, but on the second call the property is set back to "Nothing". As for reasoning, the first call is to would be to check if properties on the client side are valid (such as a serial number), and to let the service know which client it is working with. The next calls would be to retrieve information about that about that client, basic info such as name, telephone, etc.)

I could pass the serial number each time, but I thought it would be better to only need to pass that once, and grab other information as its needed.

Comment: How do you know it's a single instance? Care to show some code?

Comment: I've edited the original question (poorly) to include some code. Thank you for the responses, and please let me know if theres anything else I can include to help troubleshoot the issue.